# After Decompilng exe with JetBrains dotPeek and Exporting as a C# Project, all Variablse are, "already defined"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, decompiling, dotpeek

I'm trying to decompile a fairly simple .exe with JetBrains dotPeek and then re-build it.  I've so far decompiled it, and exported it as a .csproj, but when opened in Visual Studio 2015, almost all variables get the error:

```
The type 'MainWindow' already contains a definition for 'winMain'
```

It appears to be an issue between the .xaml form markup and the .xaml.cs code.

What's the meaning of this conflict?  Is there a practical way to resolve them?